# HTML Inline Expression for AJAToolKit

Tags: html, asp.net-ajax, inline, autocompleteextender

I would like to assign dynamic ID to my AutoCompleteExtenders, but i am having problem using the usual inline expressions such as `<%=variable%>` for anything within the `<autoCompleteExtender>` tags

These are the tags I tried (found them on the net):

1. `<%= %>`
2. `'<%= %>'`
3. Also, I switched out the double quotes for single (but I get "The server tag is not well formed" error)

**HTML**

```
<ajaxToolkit:autocompleteextender 
    runat="server"
    ID="<%=variable%>">
</ajaxToolkit:autocompleteextender>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tons of research, inline expression seems to be unsupported for server controlled inputs. Which kind of makes sense.